# How fast is a mkdir propagated from one client to another on NFS4?

Tags: nfs, mkdir

I read that `mkdir` is not atomic on NFS. Does that mean that two clients can at the same time `mkdir` the same directory without failing with EEXIST?

How fast is then a `mkdir` propagated from one client to another on NFS4?

> To detect when directory entries have been added or removed on the server, the Linux NFS client watches a directory's mtime. If the client detects a change in a directory's mtime, the client drops all cached LOOKUP results for that directory. Since the directory's mtime is a cached attribute, it may take some time before a client notices it has changed. See the descriptions of the acdirmin, acdirmax, and noac mount options for more information about how long a directory's mtime is cached. ([man nfs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs))

So it might take up to `acdirmax` seconds until a client detects a change on the server.

I guess that in case of a `mkdir`, a NFS client checks that the new directory does not already exist in the local cache, and then proceeds with creating the directory. In parallel, a second client can do the same. Is that right? What happens of the server in this case?

Shouldn't the client rather tell the server to atomically `mkdir` the directory and wait for the result?